# Angular 12 and .NET 5,access from origin localhost:4200 has been blocked by CORS policy With Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-core

I am getting an error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:17822/api/Accounts/TestPOST' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource**, while requesting back endpoint with "POST" action.

Back-End service on IIS is only enabled with "**Windows Authentication**".

**Angular**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    request = request.clone({
      withCredentials: true
    });

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```cs
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
    _ = services.AddCors(opt => {
      opt.AddPolicy(AppCorsPolices.MainCorsPolicy.ToString(), policy => {
        policy.WithOrigins(_config.GetValue < string > ("ClientApps:AdminPanel"))
          .AllowAnyHeader()
          .AllowAnyMethod()
          .AllowCredentials();
      });
    });

    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();

            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Errors/{0}");

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseCors(AppCorsPolices.MainCorsPolicy.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What does this: config.GetValue < string > ("ClientApps:AdminPanel") return?

Comment: "ClientApps": {
    "AdminPanel": "http://localhost:4200",
  },

Comment: Hi @AhmedLotfi, what if you change AdminPanel value to `http://localhost:4200`? If still does not work, try to add `.SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)` after `AllowCredentials()`.

Comment: I tried this before it did not work also.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your configuration for enabling windows authentication is not complete. If you use IIS Express you should modify Properties\launchSettings.json to add windowsAuthentication with true value.

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:3381/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Also, you should add forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" to web.config like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%"
            stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
            forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you launch as SelfHost, modify Program.cs and add HttpSys:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                                     .UseKestrel()
                                     .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                     .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                     .UseHttpSys(options => // Just for local tests without IIS, Or self-hosted scenarios on Windows ...
                                     {
                                         options.Authentication.Schemes =
                                              AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate | AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM;
                                         options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
                                         //options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://+:80/");
                                     })
                                     .Build();
            host.Run();
        }
    }
```

And if you use IIS Add UseIISIntegration:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                                 .UseKestrel()
                                 .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                 .UseIISIntegration()
                                 .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
                                 {
                                     options.ValidateScopes = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
                                 })
                                 .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                 .Build();
        host.Run();
    }
}
```

And change Startup.cs to add AddAuthentication with IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Sets the HttpContext.User
                // Note: Windows Authentication must also be enabled in IIS for this to work.
                options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
                options.ForwardClientCertificate = true;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                // for both windows and anonymous authentication
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            });
        }
```